# Avoid accepting 301 requests for robots.txt?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We changed from olddomain.com to newdomain.com. After using an .htaccess (to handle the 301s) on olddomain.com for around 6 months, we cancelled the hosting of olddomain.com and then reverted to using a blanket 301 redirect service provided by our domain registrar.

This generally works fine, but we noticed that www.olddomain.com/robots.txt is now redirecting via the blanket 301 to www.newdomain.com/robots.txt and this seems to be creating various errors with our Google listing and Webmaster Tools.

So, to the question: Is there something I can add to our newdomain.com .htaccess file which will NOT accept requests for robots.txt from olddomain.com? I can't do anything at olddomain.com as its now just with the registrar and has no files/hosting.

I thought this should work, but it doesn't appear to.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.txt$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^robots\.txt http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: No, because as explained I can't access any kind of rewrite file on the olddomain.com now it is a the domain registrar using a blanket 301 redirect service. Please read y question :)

Comment: oh sorry for misunderstanding. No `%{HTTP_REFERER}` won't work since bots are not clicking on any link on old site.

Comment: When you say "bot" I'm assuming you mean whatever software the domain registrar is using to do the redirects? Is there no solution to this problem?

Comment: By bots I means search engine bots. If you own `olddomain.com` then you can simply create a CNAME and point it to `newdomain.com` and use edited code above.

Comment: Right but if I make it a CNAME then it won't 301 any old links to their new places on newdomain.com?

Comment: No that's not correct. Once you create a CNAME above rule will start working by redirecting all olddomain links to newdomain with 301

Comment: Do I need to delete the @ and * A records for olddomain.com which currently point to the domain registrar's IP address? I'm not clear how I use CNAME records to redirect olddomain.com to newdomain.com. Can I have a domain that just has a CNAME?

Comment: As an alternative to CNAME you can just modify the A record to point at same IP as the newdomain.com

Comment: Right but the problem with your suggestions is that olddomain.com will continue to appear in the browser address bar even though they are looking at newdomain.com? Also if I point olddomain.com at the IP address of newdomain.com then on the hosting package at newdomain.com I'd need to create a virtual host which I can't do?

Comment: No it will NOT appear in the browser because of the rule I gave above. That rule will make any `http://olddomain.com/anything` to `http://newdomain.com/anything` with 301 (permanent redirect)

Comment: Ok, and the edited question there about having to set something up on the newdomain.com server so it recognises requests for olddomain.com?

Comment: I posted the question there again anyway, in the post directly above your last comment, thanks

Comment: Sorry I am not an admin so I don't know if you cannot create `VirtualHost` entry then how would you do it.